# Why does cygwin mintty type 8~ (tilde) on its own?

Tags: cygwin, mintty

CYGWIN_NT-6.3 x86_64

I open and use a terminal (mintty) and every so often an

> 8~

or simply

> ~

will appear on the commandline.

Why does this happen and how do I prevent this from happening.

Comment: Any unicode involved?

Comment: Involved in what?  LANG=C.UTF-8, if that is what you mean.

Comment: I mean in any output going to the terminal (startup scripts, prompt, whatever).

Answer (score 4):

Found the cause.

I run a utility to keep my windows machine from going to sleep.  In the background it creates an event for key-up for F15.

This has been transparent until using cywin.

Comment: I've discovered the same issue on my machine. I am running a tool called 'caffeine' that keeps my machine awake.

Answer (score 3):

If the utility that is causing this input is [Caffeine](https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/) sending a F15 key up event, you can prevent it from happening in two ways:

1. Prevent F15 from being interpreted on the mintty side: Add the following line to your mintty config file (e.g. `~/.minttyrc`). It tells mintty to ignore F15 by itself or with the Ctrl modifier, which does the trick for me (by itself, it produces `~`, and with Ctrl, `;5~`):

   ```
   KeyFunctions=F15:void;C+F15:void
   ```
2. Prevent Caffeine from sending F15 by running it with the `-useshift` option.

I guess the first way is preferrable, because it keeps all the benefits of using the F15 key up event.